# EINVALIDPACKAGENAME using socket.io-client in firebase Nuxt 3 app

Tags: firebase, socket.io, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nitro

I have a Nuxt 3 application that uses socket.io-client. The app builds and runs fine during development with a vanilla `nuxt build` process.

When I attempt to build and deploy to Firebase using the "firebase" preset for Nitro (`NITRO_PRESET=firebase nuxt build`), however, the resulting package fails to install with this error:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "socket.io-client/build/esm-debug" of package "socket.io-client/build/esm-debug@4.4.0": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
```

I can see that this "socket.io-client/build/esm-debug" package is, in fact, referenced in the package.json that was generated and placed in `.output/server/package.json` (even though it is not referenced anywhere in my own project). I get the same error message when I run `npm install` locally in this directory.

It seems that this package is being injected by the build process for some reason, and the module name is making npm unhappy. Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Using node 18, socket.io-client@4.6.1

Abbreviated output from build process:

```
> NITRO_PRESET=firebase npm run build

Nuxi 3.4.3
Nuxt 3.4.3 with Nitro 2.4.0
ℹ Building client...
ℹ vite v4.3.5 building for production...
ℹ vite v4.3.5 building SSR bundle for production...
ℹ Building Nitro Server (preset: firebase)
✔ Nitro server built                                                                                                                                        
Σ Total size: 16.7 MB (3.87 MB gzip)
✔ You can deploy this build using npx firebase deploy
```